# Ant Design's Time Picker color

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is there an easy and quick way to modify these colors?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the documentation from Ant Design,

> popupStyle  |   The style of panel | CSSProperties

you could use `popupStyle` as a prop and just use normal CSS to style timepicker.

or

you could use `popupClassName`, `popupClassName={classes.timepicker}`

```
timepicker: {
    "& .ant-picker-footer": {
        color: "#your color",
    },
}
```

you could find the correct `className` in dev tools.

**Edit:**

1. Here is a simple method with the use of `className` .

```
  className="timepicker-background"
```

and in CSS we have,

```
.timepicker-background {
  background-color: rgb(26, 25, 29);
  border-color: rgb(247, 30, 30);
}
```

2. Here is another method with the use of `popupStyles`

```
  popupStyle={{ fontSize: 30 }}
```

[image]

[Demo in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-pond-579t2q?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain a little bit more in depth? I've never done this, so i'm kinda lost. I tried appending a class and changing something, but it didn't work, then i checked the class that shows in dev tools and tried to modify it, also didn't work.

Comment: @JoséCarlos please check my edited answer